# Как заблокировать любые нажатия на экран и при этом оставлять телефон включенным?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Как сделать так чтобы при нажатие на кнопку android приложения, выйти из приложения и поверх всех окон блокировать тач скрин, нажатие на экран. А потом возвращать рабочее состояние тач скрина, нажатия на экран как только будет нажата функциональная кнопка приложения сверху, в шторке телефона. Возможно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверно вам требуется что то типа прозрачного активити. Но не думаю это то что вы хотите. При нажатие на кнопку домой приложение свернется и тач скрин не будет блокироваться. Кнопки так же не будут блокироваться (Кроме кнопки назад).

Comment: Окей, спасибо за направление. Обязательно попробую